# Automating a Current Process using Batch File

Tags: java, batch-file

There is a manual process which is done correctly, I need few ideas to automate it. Please share me your ideas.

**The Process.**

1. Place the input files in the Input directory.
2. Once the files are in place, the java code starts the processing of files automatically. A file listener is implemented for this.
3. During the process, a Log file is created in the log directory and updated as the process continues.
4. Once the code completes processing the files, output files are generated in the work directory.
5. The output files are archived along with the input file and moved to archive directory.

**Manual Work that is being done!**

1. The input files comes from different sources and different names. The files are renamed based on the input files name. Each input file name has an identifier with which I rename the files.
2. Starting the file listener manually.
3. Placing the input file in the input directory.
4. once the processing completes, read the log and check if the code processed successfully or not.
5. if successful, I copy the archive from the archive directory, extract the output file, rename it according to previous input file and move it to outbound directory.
6. Then again start from step 1 for the next file.

Is there a way to create a batch file or any other idea to automate all the manual work being done.? Please share your ideas.

Comment: Well, you can  create a timer Job to perform all the manual jobs that you have listed here. This can be coded using Java or any preferable language. The timer job/application will keep polling the sources from where you receive the files after scheduled intervals. Rest of steps can be coded there itself or you can make use of Batch Jobs [link] http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html or properietory solution [link] https://flux.ly/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use the `move` command to manipulate what directory the files are in.

```
>help move
Moves files and renames files and directories.

To move one or more files:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination

To rename a directory:
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]dirname1 dirname2

  [drive:][path]filename1 Specifies the location and name of the file
                          or files you want to move.
  destination             Specifies the new location of the file. Destination
                          can consist of a drive letter and colon, a
                          directory name, or a combination. If you are moving
                          only one file, you can also include a filename if
                          you want to rename the file when you move it.
  [drive:][path]dirname1  Specifies the directory you want to rename.
  dirname2                Specifies the new name of the directory.

  /Y                      Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to
                          overwrite an existing destination file.
  /-Y                     Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite
                          an existing destination file.

The switch /Y may be present in the COPYCMD environment variable.
This may be overridden with /-Y on the command line.  Default is
to prompt on overwrites unless MOVE command is being executed from
within a batch script.
```

each file can be moved to the input directory with

```
move /Y %file% %input_dir%
```

moving files from the input directory to output or archive directory is the exactly the same.

---

Running your Java program from a batch file is the same as running it from the command line.

```
java MyClass [args...]
```

---

Creating a batch file that uses the `move` and `java` commands automatically for you will be trivial once you understand these commands.